# How can I write words in a string reverse?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am having a struggle with the following exercise in my book:

> Write a program that prompts the user to enter a series of words separated by single spaces, then prints the words in reverse order. Read the input as a string, and then use strtok to break it into words.
>
> ```
> Input:hi there you are cool
> Output: None it shuts itself.
> Expected:cool are you there hi
> ```

My program only gets the string and waits and shuts after a couple of seconds. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int ch ;
    char * str , * str2;
    char * p;
    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    str2 =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    if((fgets(str , sizeof(str) , stdin)) != NULL){
        str = strtok(str ," \t");
        p = strrchr(str , '\0');
        strcat(str2,p);
        printf("%s",p);
       while(str != NULL){
          str = strtok(NULL ," \t");
          p = strrchr(str + 1, '\0');
          strcat(str2,p);
          printf("%s",p);
       }
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

I know this question [has been asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204364/reversing-words-in-a-string-in-c). I get the idea there but my problem is implementation and carrying out. This is more of a beginner question.

Comment: can you show your output and expected output

Comment: Time to learn to use a debugger: What happens when `str` is `NULL` when `strrchr` is called ?

Comment: @Mathieu Which debugger is  best? I am on Windows using GCC as a compiler.

Comment: please consider using [`strtok_r`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/), that way you get a better habit for the correct functions to use

Comment: Please read the docs for [`fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html) closely. The second argument is the number of bytes to read, but `sizeof(str)` will be the number of bytes a `char*` has. Consider using [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3p.html) instead.

Comment: Downvoters please justify your vote so i can improve on it. @Ackdari I can't use these functions in my program. When i search them online they appear to be C++ functions. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AliA But they are not, they might appear in C++ references but that's because C++ is a superset of C. So they can be used in both C and C++. For `strtok_r` you need to include `string.h` and for `getline` you need to include `stdio.h`. Please see the previusly linked resources on how you use these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you yourself stated that this is for an exercise I will not provide a working solution but an outline of what you might want to do.

Functions you want to use:

- [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3p.html) - for an easy read of an input line (notice that the newline character will not be eliminated
- [`strtok_r`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) to get the tokens (i.e. the words) from the input string

  - the `_r` means that this function is re-entrant which means that it can saftly be called by multiple threads at the same time. The normal version has an internal state and `strtok_r` lets you manage that state via a parameter.

(Please also read the docs for these functions if you have further questions)

For the algorithm:
Use `getline` to read a single line from input and replace the newline character with the 0 char. Then you should extract all one token after the other from the input and store them in a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) like fashion. After you tokenized the input just pop the token from the stack an print them to the `stdout`.

Another approach would be:

Write a function that simply reverses a string. Then use this function to reverse the input string and then for all tokens to read the token from the reversed input string and print the reverse token to `stdout`.